# Betacom Wireless not working on a fresh install of Ubuntu LTS 20.4

Tags: networking, wireless

I am failing to get Betacom Wireless working on a fresh install of Ubuntu LTS 20.4 on a 2013 iMac. I have tried the various suggestions

Late 2013 iMac with 16GB RAM, 3.1GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbodrive

Comment: Do you mean Broadcom? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)